# Java NullPointerException Getting Resources

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am writing a simple Android application (which is mainly for me to test whatever I may need to use in a real app) and I need to use a MediaPlayer to play a sound. In this case, I'm using `kalimba.mp3` (no capital letters). But when I try to run the app, it instantly crashes because of a null object reference. The error is below, as is my code. The problem is, I don't see a problem with anything, and it gives me no errors while editing my code. How do I stop this from throwing an error? I've never used a MediaPlayer before. Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

```
// Player of "kalimba.mp3"
private MediaPlayer kalimbaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalimba);

// Play/stop the sound    
public void playSound(View view) { kalimbaPlayer.start(); }
public void stopSound(View view) { kalimbaPlayer.stop(); kalimbaPlayer.release(); }
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where is this code (which class)? Do `playSound` and `stopSound` need to be public? It looks as though they are click listeners which you bind to buttons in XML - are you calling them from elsewhere? If not, then they are probably irrelevant to this problem, given that you experience this crash as soon as you run the app (without pressing any buttons)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`this` is presumably your Activity. At the time the fields are initialised, the Activity probably isn't fully ready.

Instead, initialise the MediaPlayer inside the onCreate() method of the Activity.

Comment: If I do that, my play and stop methods get angry because there is no variable "kalimbaPlayer"

Comment: You can leave the declaration `private MediaPlayer kalimbaPlayer;` where it is (note the semi colon). Then in your `onCreate()`, you initialise the variable only (don't declare it again): `kalimbaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalimba);`

Comment: Declare `private MediaPlayer kalimbaPlayer` as member variable. But, initialize `kalimbaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalimba);` inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @ataulm okay, thanks, but my original question still remains un-answered.

Comment: @WillEccles you'll probably need to provide more information (as an edit to your question, not here), such as the line on which the exception occurs, and some context into _when_ that line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

create Global variable in your class

```
 public Resources mRes;
```

After this

```
 @Override
Oncreate(Bundle saveInstance){
mRes = getActivity().getResources();
}
```

Now user mRes object to get resource....
For example

`mRes.getString(R.string.SEARCH);`

Answer (score -3):

you used onCreate

kalimbaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(nameActivity.this, R.raw.kalimba);

pm . nameActivity = nameActivity class